# ValidationError on smart contract function call for no apparent reason?

Tags: python, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3py

I am trying to call Uniswap's Router's function [swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens()](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d#writeContract). When I enter the values manually on etherscan, it goes through. However, when I do it via python code it gives me a validation error. The error looks like this:

> web3.exceptions.ValidationError:
> Could not identify the intended function with name swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens, positional argument(s) of type (, , , , ) and keyword argument(s) of type {}.
> Found 1 function(s) with the name swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens: [swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)]
> Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.`

Here's the code im using:

```
swap = uniswap_router_contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint amount, 0, list_of_two_token_addresses, my_address_string, unix_time_stamp_deadline).buildTransaction({'nonce': some_nonce})

gas_amount = web3.eth.estimateGas(swap)

print(gas amount)
```

Am I supposed to somehow turn my ints into unsigned int in python? I tried but it didn't fix it. I'm using the web3py library. Could someone direct me to the issue or to existing code that calls said function?

I converted timestamp into int and also made sure my address strings were checksum using the web3.toChecksum method.

```
swap = uniswap_router_contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint amount, 0, list_of_two_token_addresses, my_address_string, int(unix_time_stamp_deadline)).buildTransaction({'nonce': some_nonce})
gas = web3.eth.estimateGas(swap)
print(gas)
```

When I run this it gives me this error:

> raise SolidityError(response['error']['message'])
> web3.exceptions.SolidityError: execution reverted: TransferHelper:
> TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments types that you are passing do not match the expected argument types for the function.

You are passing:

```
int, int, list, str, float
```

but the function expects:

```
uint256, uint256, address[], address, uint256
```

I'm guessing that it is the last argument, `unix_time_stamp_deadline`, that is causing the mismatch. It is a float, but the function expects an int. You can convert it to an int as you pass it to the function like this:

```
int(unix_time_stamp_deadline)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did what you suggested and it doesn't seem to give that error anymore. However, I still cannot estimate the gas on the transaction. It gives me a solidity execution error, which kind of puzzles me as im only trying to estimate the gas not actually send the transaction out. I have updated my OP if you want to take a look.